# difference between the physical address,device address and virtiual address

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

What  is the difference between *device address*, *physical address* and *virtual address*?

Actually I am trying for `mmap` in drivers, I am stuck on this concept.

Comment: *"Actually I am trying for mmap in drivers"* -- **mmap** is a userland interface.  A kernel driver would not use **mmap**.

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) says:

> The kernel normally uses virtual addresses.  Any address returned by
> kmalloc(), vmalloc(), and similar interfaces is a virtual address and can
> be stored in a "void *".
>
> The virtual memory system (TLB, page tables, etc.) translates virtual
> addresses to CPU physical addresses, which are stored as "phys_addr_t" or
> "resource_size_t".  The kernel manages device resources like registers as
> physical addresses.  These are the addresses in /proc/iomem.  The physical
> address is not directly useful to a driver; it must use ioremap() to map
> the space and produce a virtual address.
>
> I/O devices use a third kind of address: a "bus address" or "DMA address".
> If a device has registers at an MMIO address, or if it performs DMA to read
> or write system memory, the addresses used by the device are bus addresses.
> In some systems, bus addresses are identical to CPU physical addresses, but
> in general they are not.  IOMMUs and host bridges can produce arbitrary
> mappings between physical and bus addresses.
>
> Here's a picture and some examples:
>
> ```
>              CPU                  CPU                  Bus
>            Virtual              Physical             Address
>            Address              Address               Space
>             Space                Space
>
>           +-------+             +------+             +------+
>           |       |             |MMIO  |   Offset    |      |
>           |       |  Virtual    |Space |   applied   |      |
>         C +-------+ --------> B +------+ ----------> +------+ A
>           |       |  mapping    |      |   by host   |      |
> +-----+   |       |             |      |   bridge    |      |   +--------+
> |     |   |       |             +------+             |      |   |        |
> | CPU |   |       |             | RAM  |             |      |   | Device |
> |     |   |       |             |      |             |      |   |        |
> +-----+   +-------+             +------+             +------+   +--------+
>           |       |  Virtual    |Buffer|   Mapping   |      |
>         X +-------+ --------> Y +------+ <---------- +------+ Z
>           |       |  mapping    | RAM  |   by IOMMU
>           |       |             |      |
>           |       |             |      |
>           +-------+             +------+
> ```
>
> During the enumeration process, the kernel learns about I/O devices and
> their MMIO space and the host bridges that connect them to the system.  For
> example, if a PCI device has a BAR, the kernel reads the bus address (A)
> from the BAR and converts it to a CPU physical address (B).  The address B
> is stored in a struct resource and usually exposed via /proc/iomem.  When a
> driver claims a device, it typically uses ioremap() to map physical address
> B at a virtual address (C).  It can then use, e.g., ioread32(C), to access
> the device registers at bus address A.
>
> If the device supports DMA, the driver sets up a buffer using kmalloc() or
> a similar interface, which returns a virtual address (X).  The virtual
> memory system maps X to a physical address (Y) in system RAM.  The driver
> can use virtual address X to access the buffer, but the device itself
> cannot because DMA doesn't go through the CPU virtual memory system.
>
> In some simple systems, the device can do DMA directly to physical address
> Y.  But in many others, there is IOMMU hardware that translates bus
> addresses to physical addresses, e.g., it translates Z to Y.  This is part
> of the reason for the DMA API: the driver can give a virtual address X to
> an interface like dma_map_single(), which sets up any required IOMMU
> mapping and returns the bus address Z.  The driver then tells the device to
> do DMA to Z, and the IOMMU maps it to the buffer at address Y in system
> RAM.