# difference between device address and physical address?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kernel32

Is there any difference between physical address and device address? Otherwise Device address is a part of physical address?

Comment: The "device address" is the bus address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between the physical address,device address and virtiual address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903841/difference-between-the-physical-address-device-address-and-virtiual-address)

Comment: *"Is there any difference ..."* -- Yes. Not all physical addresses are device addresses.  Devices address, depending on the processor architecture, could be memory mapped or I/O mapped (aka I/O port addresses).